# Как сделать половину строки заглавными буквами?

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String a;
    String b = "";
    int i;
    a = str.getText();
    for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i)))
        {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)))
                b += Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    res.setText(b);
}
```

Нужно сделать первую половину строки заглавными буквами. У меня делает все. Как разделить строку? 
(пример должен выглядить следующим образом : к примеру, вводим "ааааааАа"  должно преобразовать в "ААААааАа"  - или "аааа" в "ААаа"

Comment: пробовали `i < a.length() / 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы кажется забыли добавлять уже заглавные буквы.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String a;
    String b = "";
    int i;
    a = str.getText();
    for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(a.charAt(i)))
        {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(a.charAt(i)) && a.length()/2 > i )
                b += Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(i));
            else
                b += a.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    res.setText(b);
}
```

Comment: он почемуто не работает так как нужно .

Comment: Не так поставил условие, поправил

Comment: Golachev работает. Спасибо, выручил !

Answer (score 2):

Вы в условии цикла пробегаетесь по всей строке. Вам же надо по половине только. Значит надо цикл заканчивать на половине строки, указав в условии только половину длины строки

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length() / 2; i++)
```

Comment: Все хорошо , но оно обрезает вторую часть к примеру : "аааааа" ответ - "ААА"      , а нужно чтобы было "АААааа"

Answer (score 2):

Пробегайся до половины строки, то есть `a.length()/2`

Comment: @Геверг Арутюнян Все хорошо , но оно обрезает вторую часть к примеру : "аааааа" ответ - "ААА" , а нужно чтобы было "АААааа"